# Tcp/ip c# server connection refused

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpserver

Server Code

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using SimpleTCP;
using System.Net;

namespace TCP_server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            SimpleTcpServer server = new SimpleTcpServer();
            server.Delimiter = 0x13;
            server.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("172.16.1.121"); // My internal ip
            int port = 2003;
            server.Start(ip, port);
            Console.WriteLine("Server started at " + ip + ":" + port);
            Console.ReadLine();
            server.Stop();
        }

        static void Server_DataReceived(object sender, Message e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.MessageString);
            string replyMessage = String.Format(":" + e.MessageString);
            e.ReplyLine(replyMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

It works on localhost but when I tested on these websites:
https://canyouseeme.org/
https://check-host.net/check-tcp
I got "connection timeout", after turning off firewall it now shows "connection refused".

My port forwarding works.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: A host on the internet is not going to be able to connect to a local address in your internal network, so this simply won't work, unless you've left out some important detail

Comment: This is the opposite way around, and considered bad for a security. You generally have a server, and clients. The server is remote, and accepts connections. The client can be behind firewalls and connect to servers.

Comment: @joni when checking connection on these sites i was using my public ip, when i tired using public ip in my server setup it was showing me errors so I figured out i have to use internal, am I wrong?

Comment: Does your machine have a public IP address that can be accessed directly from the internet? Asking because that is somewhat unusual

Comment: yes it does, I was hosting website before, so its not a problem

Comment: *when i tired using public ip in my server setup it was showing me errors* What errors did you see when using the public IP address? Have you tried using `IPAddress.Any` instead of the address for a specific network interface?

Comment: im not on my pc at the moment but it was something like "ip adress isnt valid in this context"

Comment: Server should listen to IPAddress.Any so it doesn't conflict with client.  Code will only file if another app is using port 2003.

Comment: im still getting "connection refused" after changing to IPAdress.Any